# create new growth data table based on existing one indexing to a date in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe: `df1`

| Industry | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 | .... | 2021-04-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mining | 20 | 10 | .. | 15 |
| construction | 120 | 40 | .. | 20 |

I want to create a new dataframe that set a reference date to i.e 2020-02-01, then for the remaining dates, it will calculate the growth rate from that anchor date per row.

so ideally my new dataframe would be like this df2

| Industry | 2020-02-01 | .... | 2021-04-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mining | 0 | .. | 0.5 |
| construction | 0 | .. | -0.5 |

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem?

Comment: I tried this but each month I need to manually update it,.. there must be a better way.. df2<-df%>%
  mutate(Feb20=0, Mar20=(`2020-03-01`-`2020-02-01`)/`2020-02-01`*100, ,..... Mar21=(`2021-03-01`-`2020-02-01`)/`2020-02-01`*100, Apr21=(`2021-04-01`-`2020-02-01`)/`2020-02-01`*100 )

Comment: FYI: storing *data* as a column name is often a bad idea (not always), to me it suggests that the frame should be pivoted (reshaped) from a "wide" format to a "long" format. In this case, it means you'd have columns `"Industry"`, `"Date"`, and `"Value"`. While many functions and processes work okay in the wide format (and sometimes it is desired for reports), many other processes require a long format, and it is my opinion/belief that it usually improves some programming styles and work flows. (As always, there are exceptions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) dplyr** We can use mutate/across.  across(-1) is all but the first column of dat.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(across(-1) / `2020-02-01` - 1)
```

giving:

```
      Industry 2020-01-01 2020-02-01 2021-04-01
1       Mining          1          0        0.5
2 construction          2          0       -0.5
```

**2) collapse**  Using the collapse package we can do this.  It applies the indicated function to all but the first column.

```
library(collapse)
tfmv(dat, -1, function(x) x / dat$"2020-02-01" - 1)
```

giving:

```
      Industry 2020-01-01 2020-02-01 2021-04-01
1       Mining          1          0        0.5
2 construction          2          0       -0.5
```

**3) data.table**  This package can be used as follows.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(dat)
timecols <- names(dat)[-1]
DT[, (timecols) := .SD / `2020-02-01` - 1, .SDcols = timecols]
```

giving:

```
> DT
       Industry 2020-01-01 2020-02-01 2021-04-01
1:       Mining          1          0        0.5
2: construction          2          0       -0.5
```

**4) Base R**  With Base R we can write this:

```
replace(dat, -1, dat[-1] / dat$"2020-02-01" - 1)
```

giving:

```
      Industry 2020-01-01 2020-02-01 2021-04-01
1       Mining          1          0        0.5
2 construction          2          0       -0.5
```

### Note

```
dat <- structure(list(Industry = c("Mining", "construction"), `2020-01-01` = c(20L, 
120L), `2020-02-01` = c(10L, 40L), `2021-04-01` = c(15L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!  lots of interesting ideas!

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a rolling-window operation, so my first inclination is to use `zoo::rollapply`. (There is a new package, `slider`, though I have not tested it yet.)

The premise is to see what the improvement is from the previous value, so let's see how that works.

```r
pctimprove <- function(vec) zoo::rollapply(vec, 2, function(a) (a[2]-a[1])/a[1], fill = 0, align = "right")
pctimprove(c(10,10,15))
# [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5
pctimprove(c(40,20,15))
# [1]  0.00 -0.50 -0.25
```

Now, let's apply that to your data.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Industry = c("Mining", "construction"), `2020-02-01` = c(10, 40), `2020-03-01` = c(10, 20), `2020-04-01` = c(15, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
dat
#       Industry 2020-02-01 2020-03-01 2020-04-01
# 1       Mining         10         10         15
# 2 construction         40         20         15
apply(dat[,2:4], 1, pctimprove)
#            [,1]  [,2]
#             0.0  0.00
# 2020-03-01  0.0 -0.50
# 2020-04-01  0.5 -0.25
```

In this case, `apply` is transposing the return (for several reasons, press the *"I believe"* button), so we can transpose it and reassign back into the frame.

```r
t(apply(dat[,2:4], 1, pctimprove))
#        2020-03-01 2020-04-01
# [1,] 0        0.0       0.50
# [2,] 0       -0.5      -0.25
dat[,2:4] <- t(apply(dat[,2:4], 1, pctimprove))
dat
#       Industry 2020-02-01 2020-03-01 2020-04-01
# 1       Mining          0        0.0       0.50
# 2 construction          0       -0.5      -0.25
```

If you need this in a new frame instead, then copy it before running that sequence.

---

Like I mentioned in my comment, though, storing *data* as a column name is often a bad idea (not always), to me it suggests that the frame should be pivoted (reshaped) from a "wide" format to a "long" format. In this case, it means you'd have columns `"Industry"`, `"Date"`, and `"Value"`. While many functions and processes work okay in the wide format (and sometimes it is desired for reports), many other processes require a long format (e.g., `ggplot2`), and it is my opinion/belief that it usually improves some programming styles and work flows. (As always, there are exceptions.)

Here's a couple of approaches to consider, starting with the original `dat`.

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Industry, names_to = "Date", values_to = "Value")
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Industry     Date       Value
#   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Mining       2020-02-01    10
# 2 Mining       2020-03-01    10
# 3 Mining       2020-04-01    15
# 4 construction 2020-02-01    40
# 5 construction 2020-03-01    20
# 6 construction 2020-04-01    15
```

From here, my above is simply:

```r
dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Industry, names_to = "Date", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(Industry) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = pctimprove(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   Industry     Date       Value Value2
#   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Mining       2020-02-01    10   0   
# 2 Mining       2020-03-01    10   0   
# 3 Mining       2020-04-01    15   0.5 
# 4 construction 2020-02-01    40   0   
# 5 construction 2020-03-01    20  -0.5 
# 6 construction 2020-04-01    15  -0.25
```

(Another advantage of the long format is that it is easier to store both values here.)

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
melt(DT, "Industry", variable.name = "Date", value.name = "Value"
  )[, Value2 := pctimprove(Value), by = Industry][]
#        Industry       Date Value Value2
#          <char>     <fctr> <num>  <num>
# 1:       Mining 2020-02-01    10   0.00
# 2: construction 2020-02-01    40   0.00
# 3:       Mining 2020-03-01    10   0.00
# 4: construction 2020-03-01    20  -0.50
# 5:       Mining 2020-04-01    15   0.50
# 6: construction 2020-04-01    15  -0.25
```